# Reasonable way to customize ( change ) an executable program's command ( name ) , in terminal

Tags: linux, shell, environment-variables, symlink, executable

### Background

Using `xfce4-terminal` as an example, **I want to run the program by just typing `term`.**

When I type `which xfce4-terminal` it returns `/usr/bin/xfce4-terminal`.

So, I created a symbolic link: `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/xfce4-terminal /usr/bin/term`.

Now I can execute the program by typing `term`.

### Question

I've been wondering if this is a reasonable way to achieve the purpose. Asking for the *best* method (without even researching) may be a subjective question, but here I'm asking for a standard way if any, or any pros and cons my method may has.

I have thought of the following alternatives:

- Rename the program: `mv xfce4-terminal term`
- Use environmental variables (but there are many ways to do this...)
- Avoid being lazy in the first place

I already know that:

- I can utilize <kbd>Tab</kbd> to auto-complete
- (In GUI) I can utilize shortcuts like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- Creating symbolic link has risk of conflict if another program was named "term"
- Renaming has risk of breaking dependency

### Environment:

`uname --all` returns:

- Linux debian 4.19.0-18-amd64 #1 SMP
- Debian 4.19.208-1 (2021-09-29)
- x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: A simple alias? `alias term=xfce4-terminal`

Comment: copy to `$HOME/bin` (often in your `$PATH`) under name of your choice ?

Comment: If you want to go the symlink route, use [`update-alternatives`](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/dpkg/update-alternatives.1.en.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The safest way is to use an alias, as [they](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/493832/they) has already mentioned in the comments.

Symlinking will work as well, but be aware that some programs change their behaviour depending on the name by which they were called.
E.g. bash-scripts checking the content of `$0` and calling different functions depending on it.

Renaming the program itself is asking for trouble:
Anything that depends on `xfce4-terminal` will fall flat on its face after the renaming.
And you'll have two versions of the binary on your system with the next update :-/